# Missing System.IO.Packaging classes in VS 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2008 on my Vista 64 machine, along with .Net 3.5
I have been learning about zip files and the doco keeps referring me to this library which isits states has been available since .Net 3.0.

Why is this library missing? I bout the professional version of VS 2008 (in 2008) and am at a loss to understand why it is missing.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add a reference to `WindowsBase.dll` in order to use `System.IO.Packaging`:

1. Right-click your project in the `Solution Explorer` and press `Add Reference...`.
2. Go to the `.NET` tab and scroll down to `WindowsBase`.
3. Select it and press OK.

   [image: Add Reference dialog - WindowsBase.dll]

Comment: @Orcbighter : Please mark this as the answer if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Works just like a bought one, now.

Comment: @Orcbighter : Glad to hear! Good luck!